# Laravel 5.2 Twig Bridge "Unknown "form_open" function"

Tags: php, laravel, twig, laravel-5

I recently started a new project where I am using using TwigBridge. Now I want to use `form_open` in my twig file but I get an error that `form_open` is an invalid function.

The way I use it:

```
{{ form_open({'id': 'survey-form', 'method': 'POST'}) }}
```

Require from my composer:

```
    "rcrowe/twigbridge": "^0.9.2",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
```

I followed all instructions form https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html to include the forms functionality. Does anyone have any idea how to get this problem solved?

Comment: use Form::open not form_open

Comment: @Mojtaba `::` is not opossible with Twig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. The problem was that the TwigBridge extension `TwigBridge\Extension\Laravel\Form` still was disabled. I fixed it by uncomment the Form extension in `config/twigbridge.php`.